# Are Google's scrips always that slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a little script for Google Sheets. Whenever I add something new in the table, the new values are added. If I do this quickly (enter a value and press Enter directly so that I get to the next line) the script doesn't keep up and leaves out values (lines). Has anyone ever had this problem and knows how to solve it?

I'm not concerned with how it actually works, just how I can make these lines run faster in Google Sheets.

```
function addDateTimetoCell(e){
  var pDate = new Date();
  var pSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var pRange = e.range; 
  
  switch(pRange.getColumn()){
    case 1:{
      if(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 4).getValue().length <= 0){
        pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 4).setValue(pDate);
        if(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 8).getValue() <= 0){
          pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 8).setValue(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), pRange.getColumn()).getValue());
        }
      }
      break;
    }
    case 2:{
      if(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 5).getValue().length <= 0){
        pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 5).setValue(pDate);
        if(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 9).getValue() <= 0){
          pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 9).setValue(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), pRange.getColumn()).getValue());
        }
      }
      break;
    }
    case 3:{
      if(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 6).getValue().length <= 0){
        pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 6).setValue(pDate);
        if(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 10).getValue() <= 0){
          pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), 10).setValue(pSheet.getRange(pRange.getRow(), pRange.getColumn()).getValue());
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script is pretty fast, but calls to the `SpreadsheetApp` API are very slow. You should minimize the number of calls to the API by assigning the calls to a variable especially if they are being called more than once.

I also think the code is quite not optimized. Repeating calls, unnecessary switch case usage (since there is a pattern with `case` vs `column`).

I assigned these duplicate calls to a variable and use those. Also, I did simplify the switch case to make it simpler. Test the code if it works like previously and faster.

#### Code:

```
function addDateTimetoCell(e){
  var pDate = new Date();
  var pSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var pRange = e.range; 
  var row = pRange.getRow();
  var column = pRange.getColumn();
  
  var rangeCol1 = pSheet.getRange(row, column + 3);
  if(rangeCol1.getValue().length <= 0){
    rangeCol1.setValue(pDate);
    var rangeCol2 = pSheet.getRange(row, column + 4);
    if(rangeCol2.getValue() <= 0){
      rangeCol2.setValue(rangeRC.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```